# Ajax: HTTP Basic Auth and authentication cookie

Tags: javascript, basic-authentication

I want to store the HTTP basic authentication headerline in an authentication cookie, so that I don't have to deal with the authorisation header in subsequent requests (I'm using jQuery):

```
authenticate: function(auth) {
    var header = "Basic " + $.base64.encode(auth.username + ":" + auth.password);
    document.cookie = "Authorization: " + header;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://someurl",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: auth.success,
        error: auth.error
    });
},
```

Whilst this seems to work for the first user who logs in, it doesn't work for any other users within the browser session, because the subsequent authorisation headers are added and not overwritten. I know that one could overwrite a cookie by using the `name=value` syntax, but this syntax does not apply to the authorization header.

Is there any way to get rid of the old authorization header once a new user logs in?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks, JeHo

Comment: Can you change any code on the server side? What language are you using (PHP, python, etc.)?

Comment: The server side is a selfhosted (WebServiceHost) wcf data service (written in c#). I'm owner of this host, so I could make changes to it - but I fear the possibilities are limited.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems, that it didn't work for the first user either. The problem was, that the authorization header was probably set by the browser earlier on (when I used the authentication dialog of the browser).

What I'm doing now is storing the login information in a standard name=value cookie and setting the authorization header manually.

Set the cookie:

```
var header = "Basic " + $.base64.encode(auth.username + ":" + auth.password);
document.cookie = "Authorization=" + header;
```

Read the cookie:

```
function getAuthCookie() {
   var cn = "Authorization=";
   var idx = document.cookie.indexOf(cn)

   if (idx != -1) {
       var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", idx + 1);
       if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
       return unescape(document.cookie.substring(idx + cn.length, end));
   } else {
       return "";
  }
}
```

Set the authorization header:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://someurl",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", getAuthCookie());
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: auth.success,
        error: auth.error
    });
```

This seems a bit awkward, but it works.

Warning: Make sure to encode any sensitive data that you store in the cookies or this would lead to security issue. Check [CWE](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/315.html) for more info.

Comment: Storing your users' password in plaintext anywhere (especially on the client side) is a biiiiiiiig no no. *Do not do this* (definitely not in production).

Comment: Since I still get upvotes here: William is right - This solution is completely insecure because the cookie can be read by JavaScript (moreover the content is visible in the F12 Dev Tools - since the cookie is unencrypted).

Comment: you should probably edit your answer to account for this security issue. maybe a warning at the end of the answer. i'm pretty sure when it works nobody bothers to read this section.