# FormsAuthentication and Ajax Requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication

I have a problem knowing whether a user is authenticated or not when ajax requests are sent from jQuery.

`HttpContext.User.Identity` is not empty when a user does a regular request from their browser and the `aspxauth` cookie is set. When a user tries doing a ajax request from jQuery, the `aspxauth` is not set at all.

My Web.Config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/" />
</authentication>
```

Setting the FormsAuthentication Cookie

```
var cookie = new AuthCookie
            {
                UserId = user.UserId,
                Email = user.Email,
                Name = user.Name,
                RememberMe = createPersistentCookie,
                TimeZone = user.TimeZone,
                CompanyId = user.CompanyId,
                Roles = new List<string> { user.Role ?? "user" }
            };

            string userData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cookie);
            var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, cookie.Email, DateTime.Now,
                                                       DateTime.Now.Add(FormsAuthentication.Timeout),
                                                       createPersistentCookie, userData);
            string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            var httpCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket) { Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(FormsAuthentication.Timeout) };

            _httpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie);
```

When I make requests through my broser, the auth cookie appears:
[image]

Whenever I make a request through javascript using $.get() or loading javascript scripts / Any other request through javascript, I get:
[image]

The odd thing is that on another ASP application I am using `WebSecurity` and that works perfectly. The auth cookie is always being sent back from client to server. For this `ASP MVC 5` application, when I try to use the FormAuthentication, I cannot get the AuthCookie to proceed through all requests.

Answer (score 0):

you are still able to decorate your class/method with [Authorize] and the like.  If you're looking to check inside the controller method you have access to the User Property inherited from System.Web.Mvc.Controller or System.Web.Http.ApiController depending on your controller flavor :

```
//
// Summary:
//     Returns the current principal associated with this request.
//
// Returns:
//     The current principal associated with this request.
public IPrincipal User { get; set; }
```

it can be used like so:

```
if (User != null && User.Identity != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    // user has access - process request
}
```

Edit:

Here is an example of an [Api]Controller with an ajax[able] method that uses the controller's User property instead of HttpContext's:

```
public class HelloController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult HelloWorld()
    {
        try
        {
            if (User != null && User.Identity != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return Ok("Hello There " + User.Identity.Name + "!");
            }
           else
            {
                return Ok("Hello There Anonymous!");
            }
        }
        catch { throw; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The User is not being set when the object is from a ajax request

Comment: This User object doesn't come from the HttpContext, it's directly from the controller. It is resolved when ANY controller method is invoked, regardless of what 'type' the request is.  I assume your ajax requests are calling to controller methods correct?

Comment: Currently I'm using an authorization attribute ontop of the Action called `CustomAuth` that checks if the User is null and whatnot, however, when I'm doing an ajax request, It's always null. Dosen't the HttpContext get passed to my attribute?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure.  In my experience the HttpContext is only available on traditional controller requests (ActionResult).  So for my ajax controller methods I rely on the User property directly since it doesn't seem as though the custom auth decorators fire on api controllers (?).

Comment: The problem is that when I'm doing a jQuery request to the server, the aspx auth does not get transferred over. It is deliberately like that so that it is secured. Regular Controller requests work fine through the browser, however, manual jQuery requests just pass the barebones. How do others tell if the jQuery request is a secure one or not?

Comment: Can you give an example of what your jQuery request looks like and the controller method it's hitting? It might help better understand the problem you're facing.

Comment: I have added more information. I use a regular `$.get()`. On my other application which I use WebSecurity, everything works fine. From what I know, they are both basically the same thing except that WebSecurity does alot of database work for you. I'm doing it all myself.

Comment: I was doing more digging and it seems that the auth is not being set until I manually refresh my browser. Is there a way to pass it properly?

Comment: I'm thinking you might need to go with the full blown $.ajax() requests to make sure your auth cookie is in the header. Maybe this will get you pointed in the right direction - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455492/ajax-http-basic-auth-and-authentication-cookie)